# Mass renaming of files?

Tags: windows, batch-file, file-rename

I have a folder with 46 different text files, from 001.txt to 046.txt and I need to add another file to, say, spot 30. Is there a ways to rename all the files from 030.txt until 046.txt up by one number, so there is an empty spot for the new 030.txt? (Operating on Windows 7)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use PowerShell, which is build-in in Windows 7:

```powershell
46..30|Rename-Item -Path {'{0:000}.txt'-f$_} -NewName {'{0:000}.txt'-f($_+1)}
```

Answer (score 1):

```dos
@ECHO Off
SETLOCAL
SET "sourcedir=U:\sourcedir\t w o"
SET "insertat="
SET /p "insertat=Insert at which number ? "
IF NOT DEFINED insertat GOTO :EOF 
SET /a insertat1=1%insertat%
SET /a howmany=1
SET /p "howmany=Insert How many ? [%howmany%]"
IF "%howmany%"=="0" GOTO :EOF 


FOR /f "delims=" %%a IN (
 'dir /b /o-n /a-d "%sourcedir%\*.txt" '
 ) DO (
 CALL :isnum %%~na
 IF NOT DEFINED notnumber SET /a maxnum=1%%~na&GOTO insert
)
ECHO maxnum NOT found
GOTO :eof

:insert
SET /a newnum=maxnum + howmany
IF EXIST "%sourcedir%\%maxnum:~1%.txt" ECHO(REN "%sourcedir%\%maxnum:~1%.txt" %newnum:~1%.txt
SET /a maxnum -=1
IF %maxnum% GEQ 1%insertat% GOTO insert 

GOTO :EOF

:: Determine whether %* is purely numeric
:isnum
SET "notnumber=%~2"
IF DEFINED notnumber GOTO :EOF 
SET "notnumber=9%~1"
FOR /l %%z IN (0,1,9) DO CALL SET "notnumber=%%notnumber:%%z=%%"
GOTO :eof
```

I may as well post this regardless.

It automatically locates the highest filenumber and allows any number of slots to be inserted (default of 1 for <kbd>Enter</kbd>)

You would need to change the setting of `sourcedir` to suit your circumstances.

The required REN commands are merely `ECHO`ed for testing purposes. **After you've verified that the commands are correct**, change `ECHO(REN` to `REN` to actually rename the files.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple pure batch solution

```
@echo off
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
set increment=1
set "start=030"

for /f %%F in (
  'dir /b /a-d /o-n ???.txt^|findstr /rx "[0-9][0-9][0-9]\.txt"'
) do if "%%~nF" geq "%start%" (
  set /a new=1%%~nF+increment
  ren %%F !new:~1!%%~xF
)
```